# EventKeys in NavDropdown in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a problem with the eventKey thing in NavDropdowns.

```jsx
var Navigation = React.createClass({

  handleSelect: function(eventKey){
    console.log(eventKey);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navbar brand='Navbar' toggleNavKey={0}>
        <CollapsibleNav eventKey={0} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>

          <Nav navbar>
            <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
          </Nav> 


          <Nav navbar right hide>
            <NavItem eventKey={2}>Login</NavItem>

            <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title='NavDropdown' id='basic-nav-dropdown'>
              <MenuItem eventKey={4}>Action 1</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={5}>Action 2</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>

        </CollapsibleNav>
      </Navbar>

    )
  }
});
```

I want to be able in my selectHandler to tell what Nav element was clicked.
This works great for all elements except the NavDropdown:

Clicking the Dropdown does not trigger the selectHandler, which is fine.
But when I click one of the MenuItem, instead of giving me the eventKey, it gives me an event object.

How can I modify the NavDropdown so that it gives me the eventKey?

---

Edit: My versions are:

```
"react": "^0.14.0-beta3",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.25.100-react-pre.0",
```

Comment: could you make it a JSFiddle so I can play with it?

Comment: I am not that familiar with JSFiddle. I failed trying to get it to work with React-Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in react-bootstrap

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1268

Comment: For future reference: 
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/1604

Now:  'The various onSelect events will now consistently be called with:
eventKey, event (if any)'

Answer (score -1):

The callback on `onSelect` event will receive 2 params. The first one is event obj. The second is EventKey. You can read it in [doc](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns-props). So if you want to get event key, you should try to call it in the second param

```
handleSelect: function(event,eventKey){
 console.log(event)
console.log(eventKey);
 },
```

Comment: For some reason this is partially true. 
I used console.log(event, eventKey) and I got this output:
`1 undefined`
`2 undefined`
`SyntheticMouseEvent 3`
'''