# onSelect on NavDropdown.Item in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, nav

I have a navbar, where I want to render different components on each dropdown navitem click. I am not sure how can I derive the event Key from each navitem and use it. Currenlty, onSelect is for the whole nav. 
Please be patient with me, I am just learning React.

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect  expand="lg" variant="light" bg="light">
    <Nav onSelect={key=>{this._handleSelect(key)}}>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={C.CONTEXT_DFMP} title="DFMP">
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={C.CONTEXT_DFMP}>DFMP (District )</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={C.CONTEXT_FMU}>FMU (Forest )</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={C.CONTEXT_SILVTREAT_PARAMS}>Silviculture </NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={C.CONTEXT_SFMP} title="SFMP">
            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={C.CONTEXT_SFMP}>SFMP</NavDropdown.Item>
        </NavDropdown>                  
    </Nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I get you right, but if you want to render a new page on the dropdown click ( or a better word is to navigate), you better use react-router, and in Navbar component, you can use NavLink from react-router-dom.

Example:

```
<Router>
 <Route exact path={"/District"} component={District} />
 <Route exact path={"/Forest"} component={Forest} />
</Router>
```

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

 <NavDropdown title="DFMP" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
   <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/District">
    DFMP (District )
   </NavLink>
   <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Forest">
     FMU (Forest )
   </NavLink>
</NavDropdown>
```

More information on [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) here.

If you just want to derive the event Key from each nav item, you should use  onSelect for each Nav.item

```
<NavDropdown.Item
  eventKey="info"
  onSelect={(event, eventKey) => console.log(event, eventKey)}
>
  DFMP (District)
</NavDropdown.Item>
```

Here is similar question.
[EventKeys in NavDropdown in React-Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332557/eventkeys-in-navdropdown-in-react-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an onSelect prop to the NavDropdown.Item component

`<NavDropdown.Item onSelect={() => this._handleSelect(C.CONTEXT_DFMP)}>DFMP (District)</NavDropdown.Item>`

Comment: No it doesn't work. It still looks like picking event keys for all the navitems.